# How to read a large file and write to a text file in perl

Tags: perl, ssh

I want to capture data from a file in remote host running in unix and print it through file handle to a text file using perl.Actually I have a list of projects and try to create text file for each of them through shell command.text files created but with no contents.

** data may be large.

```
foreach my $proj(@proj_list)
{
        my $tmpl; #template file path
        open(my $fh, '>', $filename) or die "Could not open file $filename $!";
        my $cmd="findbug -p $proj |dumpbug -fnt $tmpl";
        my $line1=$ssh->capture($cmd);
        print $fh "$line1";
        close($fh); 
}
```

How to print large data into text file through shell command after reading it from remote host.

Comment: Check whether the capture succeeded.

Comment: no it is not printing anything if I print $line1,so how to solve this?

Comment: which module to used to capture data other than ssh->capture,as it is not providing any output.

Comment: Check `$ssh->error`. Come on, this is in [the documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~salva/Net-OpenSSH/lib/Net/OpenSSH.pm).

Answer (score -2):

Unless there's a reason you can't do it, just copy the files from the remote server using scp.

Alternatively, we have used several of the SSH modules, and reverted to using IPC::Run3 to run ssh as a subprocess.  One of the great things about IPC::Run3, is that you can very easily redirect the stdout and stderr to files, variables, or the file handles of the parent process.

```
use IPC::Run3;
use File::Slurp qw(write_file);

my ($in, $out, $err);
my $cmd = "ssh -l $user $host findbug -p $proj |dumpbug -fnt $tmpl";
run3( $cmd, $in, $out, $err);
write_file($tmp_file_name, $out);
```

ought to do it.

Comment: I am getting this type of error after running this--                Use of uninitialized value $_[0] in join or string at C:
/Perlinstalled/perl/vendor/lib/File/Slurp.pm line 405.               please help me.

Comment: It is not working as I am facing some error Use of uninitialized value $_[0] in join or string at C: /Perlinstalled/perl/vendor/lib/File/Slurp.pm line 405.

Comment: The parameters to write_file must contain defined values.

Comment: My psychic abilities must be waning.  I don't seem to be able to visualize the code that you say is failing.  I suggest printing out the variables you're using in your script to see what you've left uninitialized.  My suspicion is that it's $tmp_file_name.  I did not supply a value, but clearly, you must.